# Decomposition of binary strings that have an even number of blocks

Tags: combinatorics, binary

I need to compute the decomposition of binary strings that have an even number of blocks. I know general form of decomposition is $1^*(00^*11^*)^*0^*$. My question is How I can modify this decomposition to get what I need? Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify the term *block*?

Comment: a block is a maximal run of 0's or 1's. For example "11100100" has 4 blocks.

Answer (score 1):

If we collapse blocks to a single character we are asking for strings having even length and runs of length $1$ only. These are
\begin{align*}
(01)^*\cup(10)^*=\{\varepsilon,01,10,0101,1010,010101,101010,\ldots\}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Expanding each character in (1) by one or more occurrences of it $$0\longrightarrow 0^+\qquad\text{and}\qquad 1\longrightarrow 1^+$$ generates strings with an even number of blocks:
>
> \begin{align*}
> (0^+1^+)^*\cup(1^+0^+)^*
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I need.

Comment: @scottgreen: You're welcome! :-)